# Can't install xdebug on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: xdebug, homebrew

I'm kind of new to using Homebrew, but I love it.  It's so easy.  I'm trying install Xdebug.  Some of the posts on the web say to do this:

```
brew install xdebug
```

But it doesn't work.  I get: `Error, no available formula.`

I did `brew search xdebug` and it returned:

```
josegonzalez/php/php53-xdebug    josegonzalez/php/php54-xdebug
```

I tried several different iterations of `brew install` with this including `brew install php53-xdebug`, but still no luck.  Can someone help me?  I can't find anything on Xdebug's site about using Homebrew, but yet posts on the web seem to indicate it's possible.

Comment: Use MacPorts instead and go `sudo port install php56-xdebug`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Add this repository: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#readme

Then use `brew install php54-xdebug` for PHP 5.4

Or `brew install php53-xdebug` for PHP 5.3

Or `brew install php55-xdebug` for PHP 5.5

Comment: works for php5.5 respectively (tested): `brew install php55-xdebug`

Comment: how can I add the repository to brew? - brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php

Comment: Just a note for newbies like myself that to add the repo you'll need to type:
 
    brew tab josegonzalez/homebrew-php

Comment: Using homebrew, [iInstall PHP 5.6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26505558/698511), then`brew install php56-xdebug`

Comment: @Duncan, typo: `brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php`

Comment: might need to: brew untap josegonzalez/homebrew-php then brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php (josegonzalez has become homebrew-php)

Comment: Awesome it helps me alot

Comment: If exist problems after update: `brew reinstall phpXX-xdebug --build-from-source`

Comment: `could not create work tree dir '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-php': Permission denied`and then
`Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.`

Comment: I got it working with the standard brew repository, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181214/3423324

Comment: The repository doesn’t seem to exist anymore. Please update your answer.

Comment: This no longer works, we have to use `pecl` to install it now sadly. Someone get this answer unchecked.

Answer (score 121):

## // Working as of 2024

As homebrew removed the extra php repository containing a version with xdebug already installed, you have to install it manually.

### Summary

1. `brew install php@<php version>` for php
2. update your path
3. `pecl install xdebug` for xdebug

### Full step-by-step example

```bash
# update homebrew
brew update

# install a version of php, e.g. 7.0
brew install php@7.0

# now they tell you how to link it, in my case
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

# reload the file with the updated path, so we can use pecl
source ~/.bash_profile

# check that the path is to the correct php executable,
# and pecl is available
which pecl
# returns: /usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin/pecl

# install xdebug, see https://xdebug.org/docs/install#pecl
pecl install xdebug

# check that everything worked
php --version
# should show a xdebug version
# like:  with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

The `pecl install xdebug` step above ended with

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.0/7.0.30/pecl/20151012/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.6.0
Extension xdebug enabled in php.ini
```

So I didn't even need to enable the `xdebug.so` in `php.ini`.

If you need a special version of `xdebug` (e.g. your IDE doesn't like the `3.x.x` versions), you can install a specific version `xdebug-$VERSION`, e.g. `pecl install xdebug-2.9.8`.
You can find them on the [list of available versions](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug) (Thanks [Bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712017/cant-install-xdebug-on-mac-with-homebrew/50181214?noredirect=1#comment116334180_50181214))

Comment: This install method using `pecl` worked - while Placeholder's method (from xdebug.org instructions) didn't. Thanks!

Comment: You might have to run mkdir and create /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.0/7.0.30/pecl/20151012 folders.  I created them and it worked xdebug.so installed successfully on the path.

Comment: `pecl install xdebug` was bringing in version 3.0.2 for me, as opposed to 2.6.0 as per your output, which didn't seem supported by my IDE. You can specify which version to install by appending `-version_number` to the command. e.g. `pecl install xdebug-2.9.8`. You can find the full list of xdebug versions available via pecl by looking [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug).

Comment: FWIW, Xdebug 2.x is no longer supported.

Comment: [mkdir()](https://patriqueouimet.ca/tip/installing-php-and-pecl-extensions-on-macos) might fail with the `Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so'
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294`. For me the dir `pecl` was a symlink to a non-existent dir. Remove this symlink with `rm` then install with `pecl` again.

Comment: After mkdir() failed and using @RichardTylerMiles suggestion, I then had to edit the php.ini file and use the absolute path to `xdebug.so` which in my case was `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.6/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so`

Comment: mkdir() error occured for me, but running `sudo pecl install xdebug` after rm symlinks and creating the directory manually, it finally worked.

Comment: I received `mkdir()` error on MacOS M1 2020 what worked for me was described here: https://patriqueouimet.ca/tip/installing-php-and-pecl-extensions-on-macos

`pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy`
`mkdir -p {value from clipboard}`

Answer (score 20):

Updated: 09-10-2019

For PHP 5.6 & 7.0 (not anymore in brew core)

```
brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
```

Use brew bundled pecl (when php installed with brew)

PHP 5.6 example

```
brew install php@5.6
$(brew --prefix php@5.6)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug-2.5.5
```

PHP 7.0 example

```
brew install php@7.0
$(brew --prefix php@7.0)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug
```

PHP 7.1 example

```
brew install php@7.1
$(brew --prefix php@7.1)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug
```

PHP 7.2 example

```
brew install php@7.2
$(brew --prefix php@7.2)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug
```

PHP 7.3 example

```
brew install php@7.3
$(brew --prefix php@7.3)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug
```

or link with brew first

PHP 5.6 example

```
brew install php@5.6
brew link --force php@5.6
pecl install --force xdebug-2.5.5
brew unlink php@5.6
```

PHP 7.0 example

```
brew link --force php@7.0
pecl install --force xdebug
brew unlink php@7.0
```

PHP 7.1 example

```
brew link --force php@7.1
pecl install --force xdebug
brew unlink php@7.1
```

PHP 7.2 example

```
brew link --force php@7.2
pecl install --force xdebug
brew unlink php@7.2
```

PHP 7.3 example

```
brew link --force php@7.3
pecl install --force xdebug
brew unlink php@7.3
```

If php -v gives you an error stating xdebug.so could not be found (assuming the pecl install went well) then you could have "old" settings like php.ini Un-/reinstalling php with brew does not remove ini files. Upgrading php to the new format does not update ini files. Just reinstall php with brew after you removed the folder /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/ and xdebug should work.

The new brew php installation does not link. You could do that yourself if you would like to (brew link --force php@5.6) Als you could install brew-php-switcher to switch between versions.

```
brew install brew-php-switcher
brew-php-switcher 5.6 -s
php -v
brew-php-switcher 7.0 -s
php -v
```

Keep in mind if you loaded php as a service you have to restart the service.

```
brew services restart php@7.0
```

Comment: This is the easier way to install all necessary PHP modules. `brew install php@7.1 &&
$(brew --prefix php@7.1)/bin/pecl install --force xdebug`

Comment: This answer seems to be the only one who actually shows how to install Xdebug for multiple PHP versions using only Homebrew and each's PHP Pecl installation. This is great!

Answer (score 19):

Forget about **homebrew** for a moment. I have tried doing with it and it is not a that good idea stability-wise. Instead stick to the default installation guide:

### Installing XDebug on Mac OSX

1. Go to http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and paste your phpinfo() content
   there.
2. Download xdebug-2.2.5.tgz (http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.2.5.tgz)
3. Unpack the downloaded file with:

   **`tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.5.tgz`**
4. Run:

   **`cd xdebug-2.2.5`**
5. Run **phpize** (install it via homebrew if you don't have it already)

   **`phpize`**
6. As part of its output it should show (If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize):

   > Configuring for: ...
   >   Zend Module Api No:      20100525
   >   Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
7. Run:

   **`./configure`**
8. Run:

   **`make`**
9. Run:

   **`cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525`**
10. Edit /etc/php.ini and add the line:

    > zend_extension =
    >        /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so
11. Restart the web server by typing in the terminal:

    **`sudo apachectl restart`**

Comment: I know I'm digging up an old post but why would you tell him to disregard his package manager and possibly mess up his already in place config? He just simply needed to go into homebrew/php and choose his version when using brew install. This is not only bad advice but potentially dangerous. It's actually more troublesome and harder to update with your method. While it's good to know how to compile and make your own packages package managers were made for an explicit reason.

Comment: after make i'm getting a list of errors saying `In file included from ./php_xdebug.h:35:
./xdebug_code_coverage.h:47:36: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition`

Answer (score 7):

I'd found this page while googling how to install [xdebug](/questions/tagged/xdebug) for `php 7.1` on [osx](/questions/tagged/osx), and I've decided to leave here my solution:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71-xdebug
```

Maybe it'll be helpful for someone else in future...

Comment: The normal command `brew install php72-xdebug` didn't work for me. Using the full name worked. Thanks

Comment: I really wish people would stop moving things around in homebrew...$ brew install homebrew/php/php71-xdebug
Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Answer (score 5):

### Xdebug on Big Sur for php8

php8 previously installed with brew.

```
~ % pecl install xdebug
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Ouch! Check xcrun. Thank you Louis Charette:

```
~ % xcrun --show-sdk-path
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Error. Update Xcode. I just installed, and retest:

```
~ % xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools

~ % xcrun --show-sdk-path 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

That's better! Now go back and try pecl again:

```
~ % pecl install xdebug
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-3.0.2
Extension xdebug enabled in php.ini
```

And check it worked:

```
~ % php -v
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:51:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: im getting this error: Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3/pecl/20200930

Comment: Thanks @Bernievv, this really worked for me.
`❯ php -v
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2022 04:34:05) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies`

Comment: @CesarMtz Navigate to /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3 and remove the symlink with rm -f pecl, then run the `pecl install xdebug` command again. This creates the directory and fixes, per, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/41081#issuecomment-503256871

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution! Try it! ;)

1 Install developer tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

2 Instal Autoconf. This is a tool for producing shell scripts that automatically configure software

```
brew install autoconf
```

3 If you use PHP >5.6

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Have fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Catalina

Starting with Catalina (Mac OS 10.15) PHP seems to be pre-installed (check with `php -v`) It could be installed along xcode or another software (I'm not sure) But I just installed Catalina yesterday and haven't installed Homebrew yet, Also xdebug is available too. I just had to rename `/etc/php.ini.default` and add this line

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
```

Answer (score 1):

## macOS 10.14 Mojave, Homebrew, PHP 7.3, April 2020

The description given in the [following article](https://sys.cuquejo.org/install-php-7-3-xdebug-on-macos-mojave-with-homebrew/) was the only thing I could get to work on macOS 10.14 Mojave with Homebrew to install PHP 7.3 with working xdebug:

```sh
brew list | grep php | awk '{ print "brew uninstall --force "$1}' | bash        # Remove any old version of php.
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/php                                                    # To be sure, manually remove the php cellar folder.
brew untap homebrew/php                                                         # Then clean any php tap (extra repo).
brew cleanup                                                                    # Cleanup and Update your brew.
brew update
brew install php                                                                # Install the latest version of php.
pecl uninstall xdebug                                                           # Clean up old xdebug.
pecl install xdebug-beta                                                        # Install the latest version of xdebug-beta (The xdebug is not compatible with 7.3 so you need to use the xdebug-beta).
php -v                                                                          # Should now say "with Xdebug v2.9.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans"
```

Answer (score 1):

As at May 2021, after installing PHP via Homebrew just run this:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

You'll need XCode installed as above answers have indicated.

The other answers involving other brew repositories or `php74-*` package namespaces are based on the old way Homebrew worked with PHP.

Comment: For M1+ Macs, you need to make a folder '**/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl**' before.
`
$ ls -l /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/pecl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 seiv  wheel  26 21 Dec 14:52 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/pecl -> /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the repo moved, but it is available [here](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php), complete with [instructions](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#readme) on how to access it from Homebrew.

Comment: Does this install PHP as well as XDebug?  How do I just get XDebug?  I already have PHP.

Comment: @shummel7845: I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @sehummel Try compiling with `--without-homebrew-php` flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error after adding the tap and installing:

```
$ brew install "josegonzalez/php/php55"
==> Installing php55 from josegonzalez/php
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps: 
 * homebrew/php/php53
 * josegonzalez/php/php53

Please use the fully-qualified name e.g. homebrew/php/php53 to refer the formula.
```

it is because  **josegonzalez/php** has been moved to **homebrew-php/php** recently, so you will face the previous error.

The idea is pretty simple, remove the old deprecated repo **josegonzalez/php**

```
brew untap josegonzalez/php
brew tap --repair
brew update
```

See the [source](https://medium.com/@petehouston/fix-homebrew-php-error-formulae-found-in-multiple-taps-7ce5ed2f6706#.g7fayecyl) of this solution to fix any other related bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to solve zend version and xdebug 
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320160303.
The Zend Engine API version 320180731 which is installed, is newer.

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 0):

**Improved Answer for MacOS**

If you have followed the instructions written on the official docs and cannot see XDebug info using php -v command and instead getting errors, the last step you should do is the following:

1. Go to the 99-xdebug.ini file you made in the described path and add this line:

zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so"

(still errors? check your xdebug.so path if it is valid)

2. After saving the changes, restart php using the command below:

brew services restart php@7.3 (change 7.3 with your php version)

3. Then check if you can now see XDebug info using php -v command.

NOTE: "Described path" for 99-xdebug.ini is something like:

/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d (change 7.3 with your php version)

To be sure, type php --ini command.