# Xdebug install on macOS

Tags: homebrew, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug on macOS Catalina but home-brew no longer allowed to run as root. Worked fine before Catalina update.

I was running Xdebug under Mojave but Catalina upgrade broke it. Removed extension to reinstall and then hit hombrew issue: get the following error when running brew as root:

> Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
>   As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
>   build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: Can you add details about the issue you get when not running as root ?

Comment: ok so if I run homebrew as a standard user (my fault as I assumed it should be run as root) during the update of homebrew I get the following error;</br>Error: The following formula
  [#<Dependency: "python" []>, #<Options: []>]
cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
</br>but the Xcode command line tools are installed as I had to do that as virtual studio code was not recognising my git installation.</br> It then continues to install php cleanly.</br>  subsequent step to install autoconf also runs clean

Comment: I managed to install Xdebug on Catalina while building from source. See both links: https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina & https://stackoverflow.com/a/58384397/445757

Answer (score 0):

Brew should be working without using `sudo`.
If that's not the case, your homebrew install is broken and you might need to reinstall it.

In any case `brew doctor` is something you can always consult.

After you got your homebrew fixed,
looking into [Can't install xdebug on Mac with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181214/3423324) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Updating homebrew should do the trick -

```html
brew update
```