# fatal error: 'php.h' file not found when running make on xdebug in MacOS

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I try to get Xdebug ready on my Mac to use for PHP development, I inputed the output of `phpinfo()` in the official [Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) and followed the instructions. `phpize` worked, running `./configure` also works, but I'm stuck at the `make` command which outputs:

```sh
Makefile:230: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
Makefile:134: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
/bin/sh ~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/libtool --mode=compile cc   -I. -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/include -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/main -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c ~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/include -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/main -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c ~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/xdebug.o
~/Downloads/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug-3.0.4/xdebug.c:25:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
```

I tried to install the `php-dev` package through `brew`, but it does not exist. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because OSX doesn't install the PHP headers that extensions require when they are being compiled. I think you're using the OSX provided PHP.

You should instead use homebrew to install PHP, which would also install the headers, and then you can install Xdebug (and other extensions).

There are excellent instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181214/508057).

Comment: After installing PHP via `brew install php@7.4` I had to run `phpize` and `./configure` once again, now `make` is working. 