# Unable to install Xdebug after upgrading PHP

Tags: php, xdebug

I have recently upgraded my Mac to run PHP 8. I noticed Xdebug was no longer installed, so I tried to install it again but I get the following error:

```
% pecl install xdebug                 
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.15/bin/php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.15/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I tried the wizard at https://xdebug.org/wizard, but I can't get phpize installed.

My Mac is running Montery 12.0.1, any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install xdebug on Mac with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712017/cant-install-xdebug-on-mac-with-homebrew)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, I resolved it by reinstalling PHP 8.0 with homebrew as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181214/633864):

```
brew install php@8.0
```

Be careful that homebrew with also try to update all dependencies and other packages.

Then pecl worked again and I could install xdebug.

```
[22:39:40] coil@mac-mini.home:/Users/coil/Sites/strangebuzz.com$ php -v
PHP 8.0.19 (cli) (built: May 12 2022 09:09:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.19, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```