# PHP - installing Xdebug on Mac with XAMPP (Unix File)

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xdebug

I have a trouble installing [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) on my PHP project. I am on macOS Monterey M1 and I am using **XAMPP** for launching project on PHP version 7.4.28.

I followed the instructions given on their official webpage:

```text
Download xdebug-3.1.4.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-3.1.4
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).
Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902
Update /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini and add the line:
zend_extension = xdebug
```

When typing `php -v` in my terminal I first get few errors like:

> HP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_soap.dll' (tried:
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/php_soap.dll

I tried following the path and I saw that in the specific folder there is *Unix Executable File* and not the folder with added files..

[image]

How can I bypass this? I know XAMPP is not the best solution for Mac, but I see that it has been used by others.

Comment: It seems like you have `php_soap.dll` extension enabled in your init file. `.dll` is for Windows only

Comment: I would suggest installing PHP and xDebug via Brew: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712017/cant-install-xdebug-on-mac-with-homebrew

Comment: I have all of my project up and running with XAMPP so I would still try to fix the issue I have. Beside those errors, xdebug is still not installed. @Justinas

Comment: It says: ``Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).``. Did you check the FAQ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it and for everyone having the same issue:

On M1, your PHP can either be compiled for the x86_64 or arm64 architectures. The pecl tool can't guess which one it is, so if your PHP is compiled with say x86_64 and the default compiler setting is arm64, then you'll get the above warning.
This means, that sometimes you have to run PECL with:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

The arch -x86_64 part will set up the environment to compile Xdebug as x86_64 binary.

Thank you all for suppоrt!

Comment: But you are running arm architecture. Why would you compile for x86?